# How to change URLs based on a column data from the Database

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I tried a lot but I am just not able to reach the exact solution. 
I want to change the URLs of the list which is being generated by a for loop in HTML.
Here is my code for that view in views.py file:

```
class DashboardHomeViewClass(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        device_objects = device_user_data.objects.filter(User_Name = request.user.username)
        device_list = []

        for device in device_objects:
            device_list.append(device.Device_Alias_Data)

        context_logged = {'device_list': device_list}
        return render(request, "dashboardhometemplate.html", context_logged)
```

Here is the code where this context is being used in the HTML template:

```
{%for item in device_list%}
<li> <a  href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span class="hide-menu">{{item}}</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now what I need exactly is: Different links should open on clicking different list view items based on device_Alias_Data.

eg : http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/{{Device_Alias_Data}}

where **Device_Alias_Data** is character varying field in a table named **device_user_data** in my database.

Here is my urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from dashboardhome.views import DashboardHomeViewClass
from dashboardhome.views import login_view
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', login  ,{'template_name': 'login_template.html'}),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', DashboardHomeViewClass.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should make some tweaks to your `urls.py` file for this to work:

```
app_name = "dashboardhome"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', login  ,{'template_name': 'login_template.html'}),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', DashboardHomeViewClass.as_view(), name="dashboard"),
]
```

Here we added **app_name** and **name** attribute of the `url` method, this way we can make use of Django [Reverse Resolution of urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

After that you can use template builtin [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag, like this:

```
{%for item in device_list%}
<li> <a  href="{% url 'dashboardhome:dashboard' item %}" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span class="hide-menu">{{item}}</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

And this gonna result in a url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/{{item}}
```

Make sure to check out the links for more info.

I hope this will help.

Comment: My app name is "dashboardhome" so I changed files as you said but I get an error as :

`{%for item in device_list%}
                        <li> <a  href="{% url dashboardhome:dashboard item %}" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span class="hide-menu">{{item}}</span></a>
                        {% endfor %}`

And the error as - Could not parse the remainder: ':item' from 'dashboardhome:item' @yusef-bh

Comment: Oops, i missed some quotes, `href="{% url 'dashboardhome:dashboard' item %}"`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

can use def get_absolute_url() method in model.py by importing django.url.reverse 
and using url name.